# Spring fallen out of Delonghi Icona machine

Tags: maintenance

I have a little Delonghi Icona coffee machine. This morning, a small black screw and a metal spring fell out of the bottom of the water container.

Can anyone please tell me how to fit it back in? I can't seem to get it to stay in.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Image of the bottom of the water jug, the black screw and the spring.]

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to put the spring in first and then insert the pin. Does it just fall out when you do that? Is it possible to lock the pin in place by rotating it while pushing it inside?